# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 geolocation get current position not working on android device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-geolocation

I try to get current position using WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition function, but I can not get current postion on all android device I've use to test and always get timeout error. 
I have add required permissions on androidmanifest.xml: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. Can you help me?

```
WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(function(res) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(res));

            }, function(err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));

            }, {timeout : 30000});
```

Comment: if you are testing on a real device please check whether u r under open sky while GPS is on or if u r indoor check for WIFI is on or not , please try these things once

Comment: I test on real device with both Wifi and GPS is on.

Comment: where exactly you are calling above function ? and try to set `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` and `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`

Comment: Agree with Hunt's latest comment about the WIFI state permissions. Please let us know what happens with those permissions set.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this would happen because the following permissions are missing in the project's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

See additional information in the following tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/location-services-native-android-applications/#acquisitionPolicy